# Button CreateJs

Tags: createjs, easeljs

Can anyone help me. Can´t make this button work... I used something similar before. I call this GameMenu as a scene inside another JS.

```
var scene = new game.GameMenu();
    scene.on(game.GameStateEvents.GAME, this.onStateEvent, this, true, {state:game.GameStates.GAME});
    stage.addChild(scene);
```

The button is here inside this code:

```
(function (window) {
window.game = window.game || {}
function GameMenu() {
    this.initialize();
}
var p = GameMenu.prototype = new createjs.Container();
p.btnIniciar;
p.Container_initialize = p.initialize;

p.initialize = function () {
    this.Container_initialize();
    this.addTitle();
    this.addButton();
}

p.addTitle = function () {
    var titulo = new createjs.Sprite(spritesheet, 'titulo');
    titulo.x = screen_width / 2 - titulo.getBounds().width/2;
    titulo.y = screen_height / 2 - titulo.getBounds().height/2;
    this.addChild(titulo);
}

p.addButton = function() {
    this.btnIniciar = new createjs.Sprite(spritesheet, 'btnIniciar');
    this.btnIniciar.mouseEnabled = true;
    this.btnIniciar.cursor = 'pointer';
    this.btnIniciar.x = screen_width / 2 - this.btnIniciar.getBounds().width/2;
    this.btnIniciar.y = (screen_height / 2 - this.btnIniciar.getBounds().height/2) + 200;
    stage.addChild(this.btnIniciar);

    this.btnIniciar.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
        console.log("Click not working");
    });

}

window.game.GameMenu = GameMenu;
}(window));
```

Comment: Are you getting an error message when you try this?  If so please post the text of the error.

Comment: Code looks fine, are you either testing locally (on file://) or loading an image cross-domain? Mouse interaction in EaselJS uses pixel checking, which doesn't work if there are cross-origin issues.

Comment: I´m using node http-server to test it. No error at all but no console log either. :/

Comment: Seems to work when using a Shape: http://jsfiddle.net/Lo2xc2cL/ -- Does that work for you?